# How do I change the upload file size limit in single-site wordpress install?

Tags: wp-admin, media, uploads, network-admin

In the multi-site wordpress install, you get a very nice "upload settings" in the network admin settings. (see attached image).

I am trying to change these settings without using php.ini for a single-site wordpress install and I can't find them anywhere...  help?

Tim

Attached: Network Admin Settings Example: [image: Network admin example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an file `php.ini` and copy via ftp or ssh to wp-admin;
inside this file the follow values; play with values for test and see the result.

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
file_uploads = On
```

Comment: Thanks - this is indeed the fix.  However, my hosting company blocked access to the php.ini (shared server) so I had to contact them to get the change made.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this thread can help you? http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-change-my-upload-limit?replies=6?

It suggests changing settings in php.ini and/or .htaccess

Comment: unfortunately - I don't have access to the php.ini file (shared server) and when I made those suggested changes to .htaccess I got an internal server error...

Comment: You can add the value if php.ini also in a file in wp-content, write a new value and works.

Answer (score 0):

I wound up contacting the customer support for my hosting company and they made the change.  I found out that the difference between wordpress single install and multi-site is that multisite lets the superadmin drill down into specific sites and set the limits for those sites.  In terms of the overall limit, wordpress single site doesn't "care" about that, and just reflects what is set on your own server.

If you have access to php.ini, you can change this setting yourself.  Otherwise, you're at the mercy of your hosting company.

Best of luck!